# AadServiceTemporarilyUnavailable. Logic Apps Error

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-logic-apps

[image]

[image]

I am trying to automate data saving email attachments using Azure Logic Apps. But I am getting the above error. Would anyone please help me how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The following statements are based on our research, please consider if the data is useful.

There might be a situation where Logic App instances run at the same time, or in parallel. Make sure you enable **Concurrency Control**.

[image]

While if you are still receiving the same then we can able to do the error handling using Azure Monitor which catches most things like malformed data.

You can also check [Handling error codes in your application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-aadsts-error-codes#handling-error-codes-in-your-application) which lists some common errors and can [Troubleshoot and diagnose workflow failures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-diagnosing-failures) accordingly.